# bad url address after detail view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a list page view at the url address ../quote. I'm loading the page with the detail, I have the address url ../quote-detail/35, where the number is any id. After loading any page, it returns an address with the prefix ../**quote-detail/**view, which is wrong and should be correct without the prefix /quote-detail/.

my part web.php:

```
Route::post('/update-data', [App\Http\Controllers\DataController::class, 'updateData']);

Route::group(['prefix'=>'quote-detail'], function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\QuoteController::class, 'quoteDetail']);
});
```

open quote-detail from blade with ajax:

```
function editFunc(id) {
    var url = "{{ 'quote-new' }}";
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
        type:"GET",
        url: url,
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
            window.location.href = res.url;
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure From php side!!! ");
        }
    });
}
```

controller:

```
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $where = $request->id;

        return response()->json(['url'=>url('quote-detail', ['id' => $where])]);
    }
```

open profile form blade:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="profile">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what returns an address with that prefix? the address bar? a hyperlink? ... also why should it not have that prefix? you are only showing a route with that prefix

Comment: It's difficult to write and explain.
I have address http://127.0.0.1:8000/quote, now click na detail-view, address is  
http://127.0.0.1:8000/quote-detail/67 - it's OK (/67 is ID). Now click on Profile, and return address is http://127.0.0.1:8000/quote-detail/profile - It's wrong, correct address should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile. Sorry, I'm new in php/laravel.

Comment: show how you are generating that link to the Profile in your blade file (view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is appending the href in your case because you're not using `/` in front. Try with

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile">
```

Comment: Simple solution, and my fault. Thank you very much.